# Proving that a functional equation is constant

Tags: functions, functional-equations

A functional equation over **ℝ** is defined as 
$$
f(x+1/y) + f(x-1/y) = 2f(x)f(1/y) 
$$

and it's given that $f(0) = 0$.

We have to **prove** that $f(x)=0$ for **all** real x.

Substituting $y$ as $1/x$, we get that  $f(2x)= 2 f^2(x)$ but I'm stuck as to any further progress.

Comment: Any hint rather than the entire solution would be equally appreciated:)

Comment: Should it be constant or 0?

Comment: Also, is it not $\mathbb{R}$ rather than the real plane?

Comment: Eh:) It will be zero and over the set of real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

- Notice how $\frac{1}{y}$ may be changed for any $z\in \mathbb{R}^*$
- Prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)=-f(-x)$
- Prove that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, f(x)=f(-x)$
- Conclude from parity arguments